# android image upload form crash

Tags: java, android

In my android application, i have an image upload form that allows a user to select a picture from the gallery.

The gallery is launched successfully but when I select a pic the application crashes and gives an npe. The weird thing is that the logcat says the npe occurred in an activity that didn't launch the image picker.

So:

New party activity launches flyer upload activity.

Flyer upload activity launches image picker for result.

I select an image and the application attempts to return to flyer upload activity but it crashes and points to npe in new party activity.

Why would it do that? I'm posting this from my phone so I will update this post with the code and logcat info in a second

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flyer_upload);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);



    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    savedPartyId = session.getCurrentPartyDetails();


    //Party service is built to make api calls.
    Partyendpoint.Builder partyBuilder = new Partyendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), null);
    partyService = partyBuilder.build();


    //get the party you just saved in the last activity
    if(savedParty == null){
        getSavedParty(savedPartyId);    
    }






}

public void pickPhoto(View view) {
    //TODO: launch the photo picker

    Intent picintent = new Intent();
     picintent.setType("image/*");
     picintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(picintent,
     "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        bitmap = getPath(data.getData());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

logcat info:

```
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mastermindcode.theincrowd/com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.NewPartyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at com.mastermindcode.theincrowd.NewPartyActivity.onCreate(NewPartyActivity.java:296)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-06 16:12:20.036: E/AndroidRuntime(5366):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you able to share code about how you go about implementing your image upload?

Comment: @BryanMuscedere i added part of the code that includes the oncreate method and the pic photo method.

Comment: What's in line 296(NewPartyActivity)?

Comment: @DigCamara at line 296 in new party activity, i  get the user datails from the session and set a string called Promoter name with the username.